# CiviRules Action to add tags not working

Tags: civirules, tags

Wordpress 5.6.1, CiviCRM 5.33.1, CiviRules 2.21
I would like to add a tag to a contact when a membership is added/renewed. I can select the action "Add Tag to entity", but I can't see any of the available tags. I can create a rule with a trigger "Contact is tagged" where I can select from the available tags. In Drupal, I can choose the action "Add Tag to contact" and it works, but I need to do it in wordpress and can't figure out the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to SE. I think this may be a bug with Civirules 2.21, where something has obviously changed as I now see the action "Add Tag to entity" rather than "Add Tag to contact which was in 2.20. I also don't get offered any tags to select. I'm guessing you may have an older version on your Drupal site. Nothing in the release notes (https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/releases) suggests this change so I suggest that you contact the email addresses in the documentation (https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/)

I'm on an older version of WordPress 2.26.2 but I don't think that will make any difference.

Comment: Just seen that there is a bug report at http://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/116

Comment: I have taken Wordpress out of the title as it also happens with Drupal on dmaster.

Comment: In trying to see what's happening here, I've also found errors in ConfigAndLog where cron cannot rebuild smart groups based on tags.  Are you also seeing this issue?

Comment: G H - I don't see what your issue has got to do with the question or my answer. This issue doesn't involve smart groups.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue.  I'm also seeing separate errors in ConfigAndLog related to smart groups built on tags.  Are they related?  Not sure at this point.  However, if you are also seeing other tag related errors in ConfigAndLog, then perhaps it's related to something in core and manifesting more prominently in CiviRules.  If you aren't, then it's more obvious I've got two distinct problems.

Comment: G H I have no smart group related errors but then I'm not using them for anything. I think its best to work on the assumption that they are two distinct problems. Given that the wording of the tag related action has changed in the latest version of Civirules where the problem shows it is most likely a bug introduced into the Civirules code.