# CiviRules not accessing 'Tags' after extension upgrade

Tags: civirules, tags

Since the CiviRules extension was upgraded, the extension no longer has access to tags.
I had a dozen rules setup that assigned a specific tag when a condition was met. None of those existing tags are showing up in the drop-downs and therefore the rules are not assigning tags when appropriate (see screenshots)[image][image]

Advice on how to fix would be appreciated.

CiviRules: 2.21
CiviCRM: 5.25.0
Wordpress: 5.4.4

Comment: There is already a bug report of this on civirules: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civirules/-/issues/116 you are more than welcome to help to fix this.

Comment: Ben, welcome to SE. When you have a question, do check to see if its already been posted to avoid duplicates. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/38792/civirules-action-to-add-tags-not-working-in-wordpress though you may have already started yours before that was posted as its also very new!